# Is is safe to assume that PHP can unserialize consistantly between minor versions

Tags: php, serialization

I am debugging a program and I am "forced" to `serialize` things in one PHP environment 7.2.3 (Ubuntu) and `unserialize` in another environment 7.2.13 (Amazon Linux).

Is there any known reason for which this should not work?

Comment: I think the serialize format has remained the same even across major version, since 4.x.

Comment: @AbraCadaver almost, `unserialize` documentation mentions only a few changes between intermediate versions.

Comment: the `unserialize()` function had some slight speed optimization and match accuracy improvements. But the result should be exactly the same in both versions. You can check by serializing a string in 7.2.3 and unserializing it in both 7.2.3 and 7.2.13 then compare the results.

Comment: No you can’t assume to 100%. As mentioned it is somehow stable. But no one is going to guarantee it.

Comment: @AsTeR, there are a few internal changes that were not documented. Those changes were attempts to improve security of unserialize and should only affect crafted (evil) serialized strings. See for example https://3v4l.org/7qYTQ. The order of the magic method calls changed a back and forth.

Comment: There's also this [Symphony bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77302), which seemed to work till 7.2.13 (it really didn't), but caused an error in 7.3. I think for most cases you should be fine, but for edge cases YMMV.